# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'duedate' cannot be null

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, pdo

Where could I be doing it wrong. I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'duedate' cannot be null

My code is as follows and I am trying to insert data into a mysql table using PDO. But it keeps sending some error that duedate cannot be empty. Even when I enter duedate in the form.

```
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['studentSession'])){
    redirectTo("index.php?tag=login&message=createA");
}else{
?>
<!-- <head> -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
var pCount  = 2;
function appendChildtoParent(){
    var idValname = "fileToUpload"+pCount;
    //alert(idValname);

    var newElem = document.createElement ("div");
    newElem.innerHTML = 'Select file to upload:<div class = "form-group">               <input type="file" name='+idValname+' id='+pCount+'></div><div class = "form-group"></div>';
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentImageDiv");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newElem);

    var fileUploadAct = document.getElementById("uploadButton1");
    fileUploadAct.value = "Upload file(s)";

    if(fileUploadAct.disabled = "true"){
        fileUploadAct.disabled = false;
    }

    pCount = pCount + 1;
}

function postHomework(){
    var description = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format :    'html'});    
    description = encodeURIComponent(description);
    var categories = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    categories = encodeURIComponent(categories);
    var question = document.getElementById("questionItself").value;
    question = encodeURIComponent(question);
    var memberID = document.getElementById("memberID").value;
    memberID = encodeURIComponent(memberID);
    var amount = document.getElementById("amountText").value;
    amount = encodeURIComponent(amount);

    //alert(description);

    if(question == ""){
        alert("Enter your question");
    }
    else if(description == ""){
        alert("Enter a description");
    }
    else if(categories == ""){
        alert("Choose category");
    }
    else if(amount == ""){
        alert("Enter amount you are willing to pay");
    }
    else{
        var tutorial = document.getElementById("checkboxIns");
        if(tutorial.checked){
            var tutorialType = "tutorial";
        }else{
            var tutorialType = "question";
        }

        var emailVal = document.getElementById("emailcheck");
        if(emailVal.checked){
            var notificatinSend = "1";
        } else{
            var notificatinSend = "2";
        }
        //alert(notificatinSend); 

        var hr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{  
            hr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        var url = "posthomeworkAJAX.php";

        var vars = "description="+description+"& categories="+categories+"&question="+question+"&memberID="+memberID+"&amount="+amount+"&tutorialType="+tutorialType+"&notificatinSend="+notificatinSend;

        //var vars = "description="+description;

        hr.open("POST",url,true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            //document.getElementById("filesUploadBTN").click();
            //alert("Saved succeessfully");
            //window.location = "my-homework";
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }

    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Processing...";
    }
}

function checkboxIns(){
    var chckIns = document.getElementById("checkboxIns");
    if(chckIns.checked){
        //alert("Checked");
        document.getElementById("tutorialCheck").innerHTML = "Check this box only if you are a teacher";
        document.getElementById("questionNotification").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("tutorialCheck").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("questionNotification").innerHTML = "Do not post private information in a question (e.g. real name, credentials) . Send it directly to the teacher doing your homework later on";
        //alert("Unchecked");
    }
}

function tempSave(attID){
    var attVal = document.getElementById(attID).value;
    if(attVal != ""){
        document.getElementById("uploadButton"+attID).value = "Click Submit to upload";
        document.getElementById("uploadButton"+attID).disabled = "true";
        document.getElementById(attID).visible = "false";

        if(pCount > 2){
            var i = pCount - 1;
            document.getElementById("textCount").value = i;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<div style="background-color:#eaeef0; width:98%; margin-left:5%; padding: 5% 5%;">
<div class = "text-center" id = "msg"></div>
</br>
<p style="background-color:#b7d3e1; width:100%; height:50px; padding:5px 5px; text-align:center;font-size:25px;">Create question or  Tutorial</p> </br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id = "checkboxIns" value="tutorial" onclick = "checkboxIns();" >Tutorial</label> <div id = "tutorialCheck" style = "color: red;"></div>
    </br>

    <input type = "hidden" id = "memberID" value = "<?php echo $studentSessionDetails['id'];?>">
    <label><h3>Due:</h3></label> </br>
            <input type = "datetime-local" name= "duedate" > </br>
    <label><h3>Title:</h3></label> </br>
    <textarea id = "questionItself" class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment"></textarea>
    <div id = "questionNotification" style = "color: red;">
    Do not post private information in a question (e.g. real name, credentials) . Send it directly to the teacher doing your homework later on
    </div>
    </br>


    <label><h3>Description:</h3></label></br>
    <textarea name = "homework" id='TypeHere' required = "required"></textarea>
    </br>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id = "emailcheck" value="emailnotification" >Yes</label> <div>Would you like to receive notifications by email when writers post answers to your question?</div>
    </br>

    <label><h3>Attachments:</h3></label>
    <div class = "form-inline">
    <form method="post" action = "fileUploadhomeWork.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class = "form-inline" target = "iframe">
    <div id = "parentImageDiv">
        Select file to upload
            <div class = "form-group">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload1" id="1">
            </div><div class = "form-group"><input type="submit" value="Upload File(s)" name="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "uploadButton1" onClick = "tempSave('1')"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "textCount" id = "textCount" value = "1">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "fileUploadFolder" value = "homeworkpost">
    <input type = "button" value = "Add Another" onClick = "appendChildtoParent();"/>
    </br></br>

    <label>Homework Field of study</label></br>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT categoryname FROM categories";
    $statement = $db->_conn->prepare($query);
    ?>
    <select id = "categories" class = "form-control" name = "categories">
    <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
    <?php 
    try{
        $statement->execute();
        if($statement->rowCount()){
            while($r = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $r->categoryname;?>"><?php echo $r->categoryname;?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else{
            ?>
            <option value="">--- No available category ---</option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </br>

    <label>I am willing to pay</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amountText">
    <input style  = "visibility: hidden;" type = "submit" name = "filesUploadBTN" id = "filesUploadBTN" style = "visible: hidden;"/></br>
    <input class = "btn btn-default" type = "button" id = "BTNPostHomework" name = "BTNPostHomework"  value = "Submit" onClick = "postHomework();"/>
    <input class = "btn btn-default" type = "submit" id = "BTNPreviewHomework" name = "BTNPreviewHomework"  value = "Preview"/>
    </form>
    </br>
    <iframe style  = "visibility: hidden;" name = "iframe"></iframe>
    <!-- </form> -->
    </br>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
   <?php
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: You don't have `duedate` in `var vars`.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your `<form>` *after* your duedate `<input>`, thus causing any data passed to the input to be ignored on form submission.

You should be able to rectify the issue by moving the form's opening tag to sit *above* your first form element.

Comment: Even if I copy the duedate input and set it anywhere below other inputs, same error occurs. Then when I remove it entirely, data gets inserted into the db. Only duedate has issues.

Comment: He's submitting the form with AJAX, not normal form submission.

Comment: `postHomework()` does not seem to handle `duedate` at all. As far as I can tell it is missing from the query string that's getting passed to AJAX...

Answer (score 1):

In `postHomework()`, you never submit the `duedate` field.

You should give it an ID, e.g.

```
<input type = "datetime-local" name= "duedate" id="duedate">
```

and then add:

```
var duedate = document.getElementById("duedate").value;
amount = encodeURIComponent(duedate);
```

and add it to the `POST` data.

```
var vars = "description="+description+"& categories="+categories+"&question="+question+"&memberID="+memberID+"&amount="+amount+"&tutorialType="+tutorialType+"&notificatinSend="+notificatinSend+"&duedate="+duedate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any input outside **Form** tag will not be submitted and you will not get that input value in your controller / Php side.

Check again your code so you will get that you have so many **input field** outside **form**
Element. That input values will not be submitted in your case.

Hope you get your solution.

Comment: But the other fields except only the duedate are being inserted into the database.... The form you see below is one for uploading the file temporarily before I submit all data.

Comment: He's submitting the form using AJAX, so it doesn't matter where the input fields are.